# How to know which service is responsible for any .exe running?

Tags: windows-8, apache-http-server, services, sony-vaio

I am trying to start Apache Tomacat server on my Sony VAIO laptop.

But it says 8080 already in use.
I have googled much on this and checked answers on superuser but none helped me.

Finally I found it myself that `"VCWebServer.exe"` is running on my laptop and that is causing the issue.

Every time I start my PC this exe automatically gets running. I want to know that which service is responsible for making this exe run. So I can make it start Manually.
Or is there any way that I can stop this exe run every time I start PC.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A little googling has told me that this is part of Sony VAIO "VCService", so this command will set it manually.

```
sc config VCService start= Manually
```

EDIT: It will spring up from time to time when set to manually, you may prefer to fully disable it.

```
sc config VCService start= DISABLED
```

Comment: Please make sure that Vaio VCService is not part of a Viao software application that you use/

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger I have set this service to Manual. But then also when I start my PC after some time this service gets started. I am starting no program

Comment: `sc config VCService start= DISABLED`

Answer (score 2):

VCWebServer is an enhancement utility from Sony(Sony vaio care). The default path on disk is `C:\Program Files\sony\vaio care\vcwebserver.exe`. The corresponding service for VCWebServer is VCService. You can change it to manual startup by using command `sc config VCService start= Manually` or goto `services.msc`, find `VCService` and from properties tab you are able to change startup to manual

Answer (score 0):

For fun I have written this powershell.ps1 script to prevent the app from running.  It runs invisibly in the background and will stop VCWebServer.exe from executing.

```
taskkill.exe /f /im VCWebServer.exe

If ((gwmi win32_process -filter "ProcessID=$PID" | select commandline).commandline -notmatch 'Hidden')
{
$COMMAND = "powershell.exe -nologo -WindowStyle Hidden -File " + "`"" + $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition + "`"" 
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic');[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::Shell("$COMMAND",0)
exit
}
    while($true)
    {
        $Query = "select * from __instanceCreationEvent within 1 where targetInstance isa 'win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.Name = 'VCWebServer.exe'"
            $Eventwatcher = New-Object management.managementEventWatcher $Query
            $Event = $Eventwatcher.waitForNextEvent()
            taskkill.exe /f /im VCWebServer.exe
    }
```

Comment: I guess Handle.exe from Sysinternals would have been useful to find the parent process in the case a future reader needs to find a different.exe's owner.